# Oracle Application Express gives ORA-06502 when submitting text field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a text field in Oracle Application Express. It is an item of type 'text area' called "P61_AGENDA_TEXT".

In the validation field, 4000 characters is set.

However, anything over 300 characters entered into the text field gives an error:

> Error encountered saving agenda item: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or
>   value error: character string buffer too small

The table column that is associated with this is varchar2(4000).

I can't work out where the 300 character setting is coming from.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I know of no type in oracle called `text area`. Are you sure of this type? I know of types like `varchar2`(up to 4000 chars) or `clob` (up to 4 gb of data). Can you please look this up? Also, can you try to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) pelase?

Comment: Says *Error encountered saving **agenda** item*, but not **p61_agenda_text** item. Probably you're copying value of one to the other.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I guess `agenda` is the table name while `p61_agenda_text` is one of its columns. OP says that the column giving the error (on saving a item of type agenda) is p61_agenda_text.

Comment: might be possible too @Chrᴉz

Comment: @Chriz He is using Oracle APEX, in it there is a page item called 'Text area', Its basically a field on the APEX site where large amounts of text are entered and you can limit the number of characters. The site then stores this text into wherever you set it(usually this would be a column in a table.

Comment: OP, you need to go into debug mode and see what throws this error, Im gonna guess that you know how to do this but if not, let me know.
I would guess its to do with whichever procedure you have saving this item.

Comment: @TineO I'm only using oracle db, but not apex. Yet I didnt find any special 'text area' troug google, I tought of a wrong data type. Thank you for this information